# JMeter: How to decode alphanumeric characters fetched in JMETER response to its valid value?

Tags: file, jmeter, decode

I have a JMeter test plan which basically downloads a file by breaking it into multiple parts.
However, these parts are received in encoded alphanumeric character format.

For instance, we have a .txt file which is broken down into 2 parts. Each part has an encoded set of characters. I have been successful so far in appending these characters into another file.
Is there a way of restoring the contents of this file ( holding alphanumeric characters) into the original .txt file with its valid contents back again?

e.g. JMeter response: `<data> aWJiZWFuLFBhbmFtYSxDb3NtZXRpY </data>`

Can someone please suggest the steps to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded, you can use [__base64Decode() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Decodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) (can be installed as a part of **Custom JMeter Functions** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager))

```
${__base64Decode(aWJiZWFuLFBhbmFtYSxDb3NtZXRpY,)}
```

[image]

If you don't have possibility or unwilling to use JMeter Plugins you can achieve the same using JMeter's built-in [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy):

```
${__groovy(new String('aWJiZWFuLFBhbmFtYSxDb3NtZXRpY'.decodeBase64()),)}
```

[image]